# JavaScript parsing metadata from audio (ICY)

Tags: javascript, metadata

I finally found a useful library to parse meta data from an audio stream, here: https://github.com/ghaiklor/icecast-parser. But still, I can't get the expected response , when I send the headers as in the example below.

The first function makes the request to the radio station / channel and gets the stream:

```
_makeRequest() {
    const request = http.request(this.getConfig('url'));

    console.log("Making request to: " + this.getConfig('url'));

    request.setHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-');
    request.setHeader('User-Agent', 'VLC/2.2.4 LibVLC/2.2.4');
    request.setHeader('Icy-MetaData', '1');
    request.setHeader('Connection', 'close');       
    request.once('response', this._onRequestResponse.bind(this));
    request.once('error', this._onRequestError.bind(this));

    request.end();

    return this;
}
```

When a request to a radio station is successfully called, this function is called:

```
_onRequestResponse(response) {

    console.log("Received response!");
    console.log("Headers:");
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']);

    const icyMetaInt = response.headers['icy-metaint'];

    console.log("icyMetaInt= " + icyMetaInt);

    if (icyMetaInt) {
      const reader = new StreamReader(icyMetaInt);

      reader.on('metadata', metadata => {

        console.log(metadata);

        this._destroyResponse(response);
        this._queueNextRequest(this.getConfig('metadataInterval'));
        this.emit('metadata', metadata);
      });

      response.pipe(reader);
      this.emit('stream', reader);
    } else {
      this._destroyResponse(response);
      this._queueNextRequest(this.getConfig('emptyInterval'));
      this.emit('empty');
    }

return this;
}
```

When I use these functions on this URL (url: 'http://streaming.radionomy.com/70-s-80-sMetal'), the reply in the console is:

> audio/mpeg
>   icyMetaInt= undefined

I understood the most crucial header here is:

> setHeader('Icy-MetaData', '1')

Still, I am not receiving the 'icyMetaInt'. The URL does seem to contain metadata when checking it with other tools.

Any ideas what is going wrong here? Thank you!
;

Answer (score 0):

Requests are part of the Fetch API, and when making cross origin requests you only have access to a limited range of headers.